# Conditional statement. How to delete value from data-toogle?

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<a type="submit" onclick="javascript:yourFunctionName();" name"save-continue-to-review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog" href="" class="btn primary btn-primary" title="Go">Go
```

JS:

```
function yourFunctionName(){
    var account_owner = document.getElementById(id_account_owner).value;
    var account_no    = document.getElementById(id_account_number).value;
    if(account_no == '' || account_owner == ''){

        alert('Alert!');

    }
}
```

How to create if this:

```
 if(account_no == '' || account_owner == ''){
       alert('Alert!');

 }
```

then delete `data-toggle="modal"` from my `a type="submit"` or change to a different value (for example: data-toggle="x" ?

Comment: Have you tried `element.removeAttribute("data-toggle")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `jquery`.

Try something like this:

```
$(this).attr("data-toggle");//returns the value of data-toggle
$(this).attr("data-toggle","");//modifies the value of data-toggle to ""
```